# Groovy uses prohibited package name

Tags: java, groovy, package-name

I've installed `groovy` on my OS X via terminal and I can't run anything. The following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:659)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:758)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.oldFindClass(RootLoader.java:175)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:147)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:100)
at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:131)
```

It seems that its developers used `java.lang` package name which makes the class loader angry.
If it can help I checked which `tools.jar` are found by `startGroovy` in the following lines:

```
208 # For Darwin, use classes.jar for TOOLS_JAR
209 TOOLS_JAR="$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar"
```

In my case `JAVA_HOME` is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

More details:

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ which groovy
/Users/maksim/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin/groovy
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/
```

`echo $CLASSPATH` is empty.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1386

Comment: I've read the thread but neither setting TOOLS_JAR to empty string nor adding sudo worked for me.

Comment: How did you install groovy? How are you running groovy?

Comment: I installed it using GVM following instructions here: http://www.groovy-lang.org/install.html#_download. I also tried to do that via brew, so the way of installation doesn't seem to be the reason.
As for the run, I tried something like `groovy --version` or just `groovy`. All of that ends up with the same result.
One more detail to note: it works in the bin/ folder.

Comment: You might have two installs set up on your path and classpath if you've installed it twice?

Comment: First, I got the error before I installed it the second time. Secondly, I did `brew uninstall` before installing it with `gym` and it completed successfully. I checked `Cellar/` folder manually.

Comment: So what does `which groovy; which java ; echo $JAVA_HOME ; echo $CLASSPATH` show?

Comment: I provided that in "More details" section.

Comment: CLASSPATH is missing though

Comment: Last one: `java -version `?

Comment: "It seems that its developers used java.lang package name" - I do not think that is correct.

Comment: Can you paste the command line you are entering before the exception?

Comment: `$ groovy --version`